# Icinga2 notifications does not execute notification command

Tags: notifications

I'm trying to configure icinga2 notification. I restart icinga2 and no error occurs. But my notification command does not execute. I defined user, template and applied notification to host, notification command for notification (as below) and turned on notification feature, i don't know why my script did not run. Anyone in forum used to configure icinga2 notification can give me full steps to configure icinga notification.

Notification Command

```
object NotificationCommand "test-notification" {
    import "plugin-notification-command"
    command = [ "/etc/icinga2/scripts/test.sh" ]}
```

Notification template

```
template Notification "generic-notification" {
    command = "test-notification"
    period = "test-24x7"
    user_groups = [ "icinga" ]}
```

User

```
object User "icinga" {
    import "generic-user"
    display_name = "Icinga 2 Admin"
    enable_notifications = true
    email = "icinga@localhost"}
```

Notification

```
apply Notification "test-notification" to Host {
    import "generic-notification"
    users = [ "icinga" ]
    assign where host.display_name}
```

Comment: What does test.sh do exactly? Anything on the (debug) logs regarding the notification execution (details on the troubleshooting docs)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to verify that the execution is not working if not happen yet. Is it executable (chmod +x test.sh)?:

In your test.sh you could do something like

```
echo "script executed" >> /tmp/doesmyscriptrun.txt
```

Have a look to your file:

```
cat /tmp/doesmyscriptrun.txt
```